# placement of scrollbar in html table

Tags: html, css

trying to put scrollbar to my table i put it but its very far away from table. how can i put it near the table

```
.html 

<h1> ASSET TABLE </h1>


<div class="table">
    <div class = "overflow-auto">
    {% render_table table_assets %}
    </div>
</div>
<h1>TASK TABLE </h1>
<div class="table">
  {% render_table table_tasks %}
</div>
```

```
.css

.overflow-auto {
    height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[it seems like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP3Ri.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a width for the parent div.

> A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).

[Block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

```css
#container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 200px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```